# Avoiding duplicate results in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following code:

```
male(prince_charles).
male(prince_andrew).
male(prince_edward).
female(princess_ann).
female(queen_elizabeth).

child_of(prince_charles, queen_elizabeth).
child_of(princess_ann, queen_elizabeth).
child_of(prince_andrew, queen_elizabeth).
child_of(prince_edward, queen_elizabeth).

throne(queen_elizabeth).

older(prince_charles, princess_ann).
older(prince_charles, prince_andrew).
older(prince_charles, prince_edward).
older(prince_andrew, prince_edward).
older(princess_ann, prince_andrew).
older(princess_ann, prince_edward).

successor(X) :-
                     male(X), 
                     older(X, Y), 
                     not(female(Y)),
                     child_of(X, A), 
                     child_of(Y, A), 
                     throne(A).

successor(X) :- 
                     female(X), 
                     child_of(X, Y), 
                     throne(Y).
```

Running `findall(X,successor(X), List).` gets me this result : `List = [prince_charles, prince_charles, prince_andrew, princess_ann].`

I am expecting `List = [prince_charles, prince_andrew, prince_edward, princess_ann].`

I've tried reordering the relations and rules, and I can't seem to get the expected list.

Why does prince_charles appear twice and prince_edward does not show up?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can use `setof`, to remove the duplicate.

Comment: Use `?- setof(t, successor(X), _).` to remove duplicates and keeping answers as they are. Or `?- setof(X, successor(X), Xs).` for the list of successors.

Comment: Your `older(X, Y)` would require an `older(prince_edward, ...` rule. Can see why it fails using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: @brebs using setof produces ```Xs = [prince_andrew, prince_charles, princess_ann].```